# Managing Common Client Side code (javascript/css)

Tags: javascript, version-control

We have multiple J2EE web applications on our platform. Many client side code (javascript/css) are common for those applications. As of now we are maintaining separate code for each applications and hence these client side code is duplicate in svn. whenever we fix any bug, we have to maintain at multiple places (for each application).

How can we maintain such client side (javascript/css) code at common place? Is there any tool available which can help us to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new repository in SVN for your common files. If you use Jenkins (or an other CI/CD tool), it can copy the files to your server while a deployment.

Second possibility: You can host your files in a content delivery network (such as Cloudfront) and add the reference to your web applications.